# React useState with a callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I'm aware that useState is asynchronous. I'm attempting to have a toggle button that will add one point to `score` if `itemSelected` is true and remove one point from `score` if `itemSelected` is false. The issue here of course is that due to the asynchronous nature of setState there is a delay so the code below doesn't work properly.

**My question: How do I get around this issue?**

```
const [score, setScore] = useState(0); 

const [itemSelected, setItemSelected] = useState(false);

const toggleItem1 = () => {
setItemSelected(!itemSelected, setCallback())
}

const setCallback = () => {

if (score < 5 && itemSelected ){ 
setScore(score + 1) 
}
if (score < 5 && !itemSelected ){ 
setScore(score - 1) 
}
if (score == 5){
completeSection()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue is that you are trying everything in one function. You are **mutating** the state and **reading** it in the same place.
I would put a controller, like `useEffect`, `useCallback` or `useMemo` to read the state, and if it satisfies a condition, it would trigger a function, like this:

```
const [score, setScore] = useState(0); 

const [itemSelected, setItemSelected] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{
if(score === 5){
completeSection()}
}
,[score])

const toggleItem1 = () => {
setItemSelected(!itemSelected, setCallback())
}


const setCallback = () => {

if (score < 5 && itemSelected ){ 
setScore(score + 1) 
}
if (score < 5 && !itemSelected ){ 
setScore(score - 1) 
}
}
```

Comment: "The other half is that itemSelected is also being read at the same time" why ? you only need `itemSelected` to update `score` based on it

Comment: read my answer to understand better how it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` hook to store the score like this

```
const score = useRef(0)
const itemSelected = useRef(false)

const toggleItem1 =() => {
  itemSelected.current = !itemSelected.current
  setCallback()
}

const setCallback() => {
  if (score.current < 5 && itemSelected.current ){ 
    score.current +=1  
  }
  if (score.current < 5 && !itemSelected.current ){ 
    score.current -=1   
  }
  if (score.current == 5){
    completeSection()
  }
}
```